# IntelliJ and maven tomcat6 deploy plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, log4j, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have been investigating the following:

```
 [INFO] Deploying war to httplocalhost:10101mywarfile
   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
   SLF4J: See httpwww.slf4j.orgcodes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

This is message I get doing a Tomcat6 deploy from inside IntelliJ using the maven run tomcat6:deploy option.

The question: Where is the IntelliJ log4j configuration file or how do you go about creating one?

Interestingly I don't get it running on the command line. Copying the command that Intellij runs when doing the maven build to a command line produces the same result. Here is the first part.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.1.4 -DskipTests tomcat6:redeploy
```

The fix to remove the error message is to add the sl4j dependency to the plugin :

```
  <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>httplocalhost10101manager</url>
            <server>TomcatServer6</server>
            <path>/mywar</path>
         </configuration>
         <!-- Prevents static binding error during deploy -->
         <dependencies>
             <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
               <version>1.7.5</version>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
       </plugin>
```

Looking at the above I was thinking sl4j-simple is a dependency of the maven tomcat6 plugin. But I downloaded the source for tomcat6-deploy plugin and a grep in it, there is no mention of the sl4fj library inside the code.

The [INFO] Deploying war to http[colon][forwardslash][forwardslash]localhost[colon]10101/mywarfile is key it shows the whole tomcat6 deployment running under a log4j kind of capture. So to get the full understanding of what is going on the final piece is how does the IntelliJ maven work and where is the default log4j configuration file.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I can search IntelliJ idea for the log4j.properties there isn't one but did confirm that IntelliJ uses slf4j. A            C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar,  C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar are present using an attrib/s style search.